# Angular 4: how to react to @input variable changes

Tags: angular

I have an input variable called model for childComponent.
@Input () model: any;

I have a parent control parentControl that send the updated input variable to childComponent.

How do I code childComponent to react to model changes?
I want a childComponent call made when model changes.

Thoughts?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: This is, unsurprisingly, in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: More precisely https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using **[ngOnChanges()](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)** lifecycle

```
@Input() model: any;
ngOnChanges(model: any) {
    this.doSomething(model);
}
```

Comment: and if there are multiple input parameters will I have one ngOnChanges for each input variable?

Comment: yes you need to do that, there is no such watchgroup in angular2 like we have in angularjs

Comment: @reza no, you don't, the argument to the single `ngOnChanges` method is actually `SimpleChanges`, which contains the changes to *any* of the inputs. You can see this in the docs linked, not sure why the author is saying otherwise.

Comment: @reza yes, you are right! actually i was mentioning about using a set_method , in that case you need separate ones. but ngOnchanges usually give whatever the inputs if they are changed. sorry i have not read your comment properly. https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: This is close, but is not actually correct.

I will give an example with a boolean data binding

```
@Input() yourData: boolean;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log('changes: ', changes); // this will console out all of the changes it detected.
  console.log('changes.yourData: ', changes.yourData); // this will console out yourData old and yourData new.
}
```

the changes.yourData would output like this in console.

```
changes.yourData: { currentValue: true, firstChange: false, previousValue: Undefined }
```
previousValue will update on second change